# MySQL sum from alias unknown column

Tags: mysql

I want to order by DESC of the total of two columns `image_gallery` and `video_gallery`.

```
 SELECT
     b.*,
     c.title as category,
     (SELECT count(*)
      FROM `movie_gallery`
      WHERE parent = b.id) as image_gallery,
     (SELECT count(*)
      FROM `movie_videos`
      WHERE parent = b.id) as video_gallery,
     (image_gallery + video_gallery) as sum_gallery'
FROM
    `movies` b 
LEFT JOIN
    `category` c on c.id = b.category_id
ORDER BY
     sum_gallery DESC
```

I get unknown column for `image_gallery` and `video_gallery` when i try to add them together to get `sum_gallery`.

How do i solve?

Comment: you are missing closing brackets of your inner selects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to an alias in the same `SELECT` statement. Instead of using correlated subqueries, use `LEFT JOIN` with grouped subqueries.

```
SELECT b.*, c.title AS category, image_gallery, video_gallery, IFNULL(image_gallery, 0) + IFNULL(video_gallery, 0) AS sum_galleries
FROM movies AS b
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON c.id = b.category_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS image_gallery
    FROM movie_gallery
    GROUP BY parent) AS d ON d.parent = b.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS video_gallery
    FROM movie_videos
    GROUP BY parent) AS e ON e.parent = b.id
ORDER BY sum_gallery DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Since aliases are only usable in the query output and you can't use them in other parts of the same query. You will need to use the **derived table** notion for this, example:

```
SELECT
    myTable.*
    (myTable.image_gallery + myTable.video_gallery) AS sum_gallery
FROM
    (SELECT
         b.*,
         c.title AS category,
         (SELECT count(*) FROM movie_gallery WHERE parent = b.id) AS image_gallery,
         (SELECT count(*) FROM movie_videos WHERE parent = b.id) AS video_gallery
     FROM
         movies AS b 
     LEFT JOIN
         category AS c ON c.id = b.category_id) AS myTable
ORDER BY
     sum_gallery DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the aliased column like that cause they won't be available by the time your query gets evaluated. You will have to use the expression fully

```
 SELECT
     b.*,
     c.title as category,
     (SELECT count(*)
      FROM `movie_gallery`
      WHERE parent = b.id) as image_gallery,
     (SELECT count(*)
      FROM `movie_videos`
      WHERE parent = b.id) as video_gallery,
     ((SELECT count(*)
      FROM `movie_gallery`
      WHERE parent = b.id) + (SELECT count(*)
      FROM `movie_gallery`
      WHERE parent = b.id)) as sum_gallery'
```